# Unable to use Google signin with expo app

Tags: android, react-native, expo

I want to add Google Signin to my expo app but I am unable to test it via Expo Go. It always say Access block: authorization error. In err details it says 400:invalid request. I double triple checked the oauth key configuration with Google Console App and it is fine.

What could be possible fix for this?